# Remove n instances of matched elements from collection

Tags: clojure

What is the best way to remove n instances of matched elements of collection-2 from collection-1?

```
(let [coll-1 [8 2]
      coll-2 [8 8 8 2]
```

Here's what I first came up with to solve original problem:

```
   ...
;; (remove (set coll-1) coll-2))
;;     --> ()
```

But realised I must achieve:

```
   ...
;; (some-magic coll-1 coll-2))
;;     --> (8 8)
```

Clarification:

```
 (some-magic {8 2} [8 8 8 2]) ;;Removes 1x8 and 1x2 from vector.
 (some-magic {8 8 2} [8 8 8 2]) ;;Removes 2x8 and 1x2 from vector.
```

**Edit:**

Preserving the order is desired.

Comment: do you want to preserve the order?

Comment: Yes that would be optimal to my aim. Achieving the first and then rearranging it would be a second choice.

Comment: You are removing `coll-1`s from `coll-2`, not the other way round. And surely better say `(some-magic {8 2} [8 8 8 2])` - in other words, specify the removals as a map imitating a multiset/bag.

Comment: You want to remove the first instance for a set of values right? Or is it the first _n_ instances? (Where a map is useful, where the map values indicate the number of instances to remove per key.)

Comment: Mike: n is the number of instances, i.e. {8 8} requires two 8 removed and {8} is one.

Comment: Ahh. Perhaps a map is needed. {8 2, 2 1} would mean remove first two 8s and first 2.

Comment: Given the clarified semantics, similar solution exists replacing set with map and revising a little logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any of the built in sequence manipulation functions quite solving this, though a straitforward loop can build the result nicely:

```
user> (loop [coll-1 (set coll-1) coll-2 coll-2 result []]
        (if-let [[f & r] coll-2]
          (if (coll-1 f)
            (recur (disj coll-1 f) r result)
            (recur coll-1 r (conj result f)))
          result))
[8 8]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a lazy solution, written in the style of `distinct`:

```
(defn some-magic [count-map coll]
  (let [step (fn step [xs count-map]
               (lazy-seq
                 ((fn [[f :as xs] count-map]
                    (when-let [s (seq xs)]
                      (if (pos? (get count-map f 0))
                        (recur (rest s) (update-in count-map [f] dec))
                        (cons f (step (rest s) count-map)))))
                   xs count-map)))]
    (step coll count-map)))
```

The first argument needs to be a map indicating how many of each value to remove:

```
(some-magic {8 1, 2 1} [8 8 8 2]) ;; Removes 1x8 and 1x2 
;=> (8 8)

(some-magic {8 2, 2 1} [8 8 8 2]) ;; Removes 2x8 and 1x2
;=> (8)
```

Here is an example dealing with falsey values and infinite input:

```
(take 10 (some-magic {3 4, 2 2, nil 1} (concat [3 nil 3 false nil 3 2] (range))))
;=> (false nil 0 1 4 5 6 7 8 9)
```